# No appearance button in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Trying to add a tracking script to a site for a client, like I've done for others in the past. Logged into their wordpress page and there was no appearance button. Has anyone heard of this before? Does anyone know of a way to get to the php files that are typically there? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: multi-site? If so, maybe multi-site network admin has not enabled users to set their own themes..  (just a guess at this point) - in either case, this is question better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's not multi-site, but I'll ask the question on the wordpress forum. Thanks for your help.